# How to know the ID of the comment for a reply?

Tags: box-api

I am trying to get a list of the comments and the replies on these comments added to a file using Box API v2. And I am using this request:
string.Format("/files/{0}/comments?fields=id,is_reply_comment,message,created_by,created_at,item,entries", fileID),

but the problem is that in the returned data the "item" is always refering to the file and not the comment that the reply is added to.

http://developers.box.com/docs/#files-view-the-comments-on-a-file

I can get the comments and get the replies, but can't link the reply to the right comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The comment object are always returned in order, and there is never more than one level of nesting e.g.

```
COMMENT

    REPLY_COMMENT

    REPLY_COMMENT

    REPLY_COMMENT

    REPLY_COMMENT

COMMENT

COMMENT
```

The `parent` field will currently always refer to the file the comment is on.